# Writing instagram crawler with Scrapy. How can I go to the next page?

Tags: python, scrapy, instagram

As an exercise, I decided to write a python script that would get all the images of the specified user. I'm somewhat familiar with Scrapy, this is why I chose it as scraping tool. Currently the script is capable of downloading the images only from the first page (12 max).

From what I can tell, instagram pages are generated by javascript. Scrapy's `response.body` (which is like source code viewed from Chrome) does not show html structure like Chrome's Inspector does. In Chrome, after 12 images, at the bottom, there's a button with link to the next page.

For example, [instagram.com/instagram](https://www.instagram.com/instagram/). Link to page 2 is [instagram.com/instagram/?max_id=1292385931151632610](https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?max_id=1292385931151632610). On page 2 there's a link to page 3 with `max_id=1287301939457754444`.

How can I grab that number in Scrapy so I can send my spider there? `response.body` doesn't even contain that number. Is there another way to reach the next page?

I know Instagram API would provide some benefits but I thought it can be done without all those tokens.

Comment: It's not really smart to crawl the instagram :) it even might be illegal

Comment: https://github.com/rarcega/instagram-scraper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to [robots.txt](https://www.instagram.com/robots.txt) policy you should avvoid crawling `/api/`, `/publicapi/` and `/query/` paths, so crawl carefully (and responsibly) on the user pagination.

Also from what I see pagination starts with a "Load more" request, that is in fact a `https://www.instagram.com/query/` request (that you need to check) with only two necessary values `owner` and `end_cursor` sent as a `POST` request.

Those values can be found in the original request body inside `'//script[contains(., "sharedData")]/text()'`

Answer (score 3):

You can also add the parameter `__a=1` (like in `https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1`) to only include the JSON in the `window._sharedData` object.

I used a shell script like this to do something similar:

```
username=instagram
max=
while :;do
  c=$(curl -s "https://www.instagram.com/$username/?__a=1&max_id=$max")
  jq -r '.user|.id as$user|.media.nodes[]?|$user+" "+.id+" "+.display_src'<<<"$c"
  max=$(jq -r .user.media.page_info.end_cursor<<<"$c")
  jq -e .user.media.page_info.has_next_page<<<"$c">/dev/null||break
done
```